# Area for multivariable function

Tags: calculus

I have to find the area of the graph of the function $z(x,y)= \arctan \frac{y}{x} $  Defined on $\{(x,y) | x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \text{ and }|x|\leq y \}$

So, I have to use integration. But how to deal with the domain? I guess I have to reformulate my domain as integration bounds, right?

Comment: If you are familiar with change of variables, you might consider using polar coordinates. Sketch the domain to see why this would apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By drawing $D = \{ (x,y) | x^2 + y^2 \le 1 ~~ \text{and} ~~ -y \le x \le y \} = \{(x,y) | x^2 + y^2 \le 1 ~~ \text{and} ~~ -1 \le \frac{x}{y} \le 1 \}$
we can actually see that it is basically a slice of the unit circle, a quarter to be exact:

$$ |x| \le y \rightarrow  -y \le x \le y$$

Is basically the function $|x|$ and all the area 'above' the function.
(I cannot post images because the lack of reputation here, and so I highly recommend you to look it up on sites such as Desmos here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator)

We can do a substitution of variables as so:

$$\begin{aligned} \left\{\begin{matrix}
u = x^2 + y^2\\ v = \frac{x}{y} 
\end{matrix}\right. \end{aligned} $$

And so our new set $D$ will be:

$$ D = \{(u,v) | u \le 1 , -1 \le v \le 1 \} $$

**Jacobian:**

$$J = \frac{D(x,y)}{D(u,v)} = \frac{1}{ \frac{D(u,v)}{D(x,y)}} = \frac{1}{\begin{vmatrix}
u_x & u_y\\ 
v_x & v_y
\end{vmatrix}} = \frac{1}{\begin{vmatrix}
2x & 2y\\ 
\frac{1}{y} & \frac{-x}{y^2}
\end{vmatrix}} = \frac{1}{-2 \frac{x^2}{y^2} -2} = \frac{1}{-2(v^2 + 1)}$$

**Back to the integral(s)**

$$ I = \int \int_{D_{uv}} \arctan( \frac{1}{v} ) \cdot \frac{1}{-2(v^2 + 1)} dudv \\ -\frac{1}{2} \left ( \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan{ \frac{1}{v}}}{1 + v^2} dv \right ) \cdot \left ( \int_{0}^{1} du \right )$$

The first integral seems intimidating, however we can notice it is an odd function meaning $f(v) = -f(-v)$ on a symmetric interval $(-1,1)$ and thus the area is $0$.